# How to sort SharePoint List column values in Power Apps Radio button

Tags: list, sorting, sharepoint, radio-button, powerapps

I have a SharePoint list "Diseases List" and inside this, I have added different columns, i.e., [Disease, Doctor name, Doctor fees]. Now, I want to bind and sort the "Disease" column values in the Radio button. For that, I have used the following code `SortByColumns('Diseases List', "Title", SortOrder.Descending)`. It is working but the radio button does not display the values [image]es.

Please suggest any solution...

Comment: Does your SP list have any data? For example, if you add a gallery and set its Items property to 'Diseases List' will it show any rows? Or if you add a label and set its Text property to `Concat('Diseases List', Title, ", ")` will it display them?

Comment: Do you have any values in "Title" column? Can you try using name of "Disease" column instead of Title? Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: From time to time, after updating the 'Items' property of the Radio button, you might need to configure again in the Advanced Settings pane the display field.